# How to serve static files in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, routes, static-files, fastapi, pkg-resources

I am trying to serve static files that I have in a package_docs directory. When I open in the browzer:

http://127.0.0.1:8001/packages/docs/index.html , the page is running.

But I want to open the page: http://127.0.0.1:8001/packages/docs/

without the source file. And the output is  `404 Not Found`

```
app.mount("/packages/docs", 
    StaticFiles(directory=pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'package_docs')
    ), 
    name="package_docs")

@app.get("/packages/docs/.*", include_in_schema=False)
def root():
    return HTMLResponse(pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, "package_docs/index.html"))


app.include_router(static.router)
app.include_router(jamcam.router, prefix="/api/v1/cams", tags=["jamcam"])
```

How can I change my code? Any advice will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: answer posted by @justin-malloy seems to be the proper one, you just have to include html=True in the StaticFiles() call.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662813/17865804), as well as this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804).

Answer (score 33):

There's a html option in Starlette that can be used within FastAPI. [Starlette Documentation](https://www.starlette.io/staticfiles/)

This would let you have something such as:

```
app.mount("/site", StaticFiles(directory="site", html = True), name="site")
```

Which would parse /site to /site/index.html, /site/foo/ to /site/foo/index.html, etc.

The other answers can help you redirect if you want to change the folder names in a way not handled by using "directory = /foo", but this is the simplest option if you simply want to load the associated .html files.

Comment: Thanks! This should be the chosen answer, and FastAPI really ought to include this in their documentation. I was putting html=True outside of that StaticFiles() function and getting error.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use FastAPI's `TemplateResponse` (actually Starlette's):

```
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="package_docs")

@app.get("/items/{id}")
async def example(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

`Request` as part of the key-value pairs in the context for Jinja2. So, you also have to declare it as query parameter. and you have to specify a html file you want to render it with Jinja `("your.html", {"request": request})`

Also to return a HTMLResponse directly you can use `HTMLResponse` from `fastapi.responses`

```
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

@app.get("/items/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_items():
    return """
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
```

You can read more about custom response from [FastAPI Custom Responses](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#htmlresponse)

Comment: This solution will work nice with javascript framework(svelte for exemple), since you can render index.html with jinja like `bundle.js?{{bundle_version}}` the page will be up to date

Comment: Closing quotes are missing in the last example `"""` in the last line.

Comment: This will break if you are using frontend templating e.g. AngularJs fyi.

Answer (score 6):

▶️ 1. You don't need to create route to serve/render homepage/static-folder explicitly. When you mark a directory as static it will automatically get the first argument as `route` of the `app.mount()` in this case it's `app.mount("/")`. So, when you enter the base `url` like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` you will get the static files.

▶️ 2. `app` instance of the `FastAPI()` class. Yes, you can have as many instance as you want in a single FASTAPI app.

▶️ 3. `api_app` instance of the `FastAPI()` for other `api` related task.

The reason 2 & 3 need because if you want to stick with just `app` instance, when user req for the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/, user will get the the static file, then when user will req for http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello then the server will try to find `hello` inside `static-folder`, but there is no `hello` inside `static-folder`!, eventually it will be a `not-found` type response. That's why it's need to be created another instance of FastAPI `api_app`, and registered with prefix `/api`(▶️  -> 5), so every req comes from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/xx`, decorator `@api_app` (▶️ -> 4) will be fired!

> `instance` declaration and `mount()` method calling order is important.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from starlette.templating import Jinja2Templates

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='homepage-app')

# for ui
#  -> 2
app = FastAPI(title="homepage-app")

# for api
#  -> 3
api_app = FastAPI(title="api-app")

# for api and route that starts with "/api" and not static
#  -> 5
app.mount("/api", api_app)

# for static files and route that starts with "/"
#  -> 1
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static-folder", html=True), name="static-folder") 

# for your other api routes you can use `api_app` instance of the FastAPI
#  -> 4
@api_app.get("/hello")
async def say_hello():
    print("hello")
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `app.mount` is not an option,
you can always manually read the file and respond with its content...

For example, if your static files are inside `/site` then:

```
from os.path import isfile
from fastapi import Response
from mimetypes import guess_type


@app.get("/site/{filename}")
async def get_site(filename):
    filename = './site/' + filename

    if not isfile(filename):
        return Response(status_code=404)

    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.read()

    content_type, _ = guess_type(filename)
    return Response(content, media_type=content_type)


@app.get("/site/")
async def get_site_default_filename():
    return await get_site('index.html')
```

Comment: Thank you. I really needed this since there's a bug with fastapi docker.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiofiles'

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/#details)

> The first "/static" refers to the sub-path this "sub-application" will be "mounted" on. So, any path that starts with "/static" will be handled by it.

This means that you mount your directory at http://127.0.0.1:8001/packages/docs/ , but you then need to either specify a file in the URL, or add a handler as you did. The problem though, is that since you mounted the path first, it will not take into consideration the following paths that include part of the path.

A possibility is to first specify the path for http://127.0.0.1:8001/packages/docs/ so that it is handled by fastapi and then to mount the folder, serving static files.

Also, I would redirect users asking for http://127.0.0.1:8001/packages/docs/ to http://127.0.0.1:8001/packages/docs/index.html