# A minimal fastapi example loading index.html

Tags: fastapi

In my project folder I have a basic `index.html` file plus static files (js, css) as well as my `main.py`:

```py
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi import Request

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="/")
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="/"))

@app.get("/")
def serve_home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", context= {"request": request})
```

How can I make fastapi work here? I just want my `index.html` and static files served on localhost.
Is it problematic not to have a `static` or `templates` folder?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Option 1: Static file mounting

It was easier than expected. Just needed to put all static files including `index.html` into `static` folder in project directory and mount static files.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

That's it. My `index.html` is now available under `http://localhost:8000/static/index.html`.

In case it should be accessible right under `http://localhost:8000/` without `/static` and the `.html` ending one needs to change two things. First it needs to be mounted on `/` instead of `/static` and an HTML flag must be set to `true` when mounting. So just use this line instead:

```py
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static",html = True), name="static")
```

(Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63805506))

The `index.html` is now available under `http://localhost:8000/`

---

### Option 2: Serving only `index.html`

As fastapi is based on starlette, a simple `FileResponse`  does the job.

```py
from starlette.responses import FileResponse 

@app.get("/")
async def read_index():
    return FileResponse('index.html')
```

Found [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/130#issuecomment-624764879).

Comment: I find that pretty baffling tbh.

Comment: Would it help if I said you can import `FileResponse` from `fastapi.responses`? It's just a class that fastapi's rendering mechanism will see as the contents of file _index.html_.

Comment: Option 1 caused my server to return `405 Method Not Allowed` on post requests, just a warning

Comment: @AryeP. that's expected as mounted static files should only allow for GET requests. Why would you fire a POST request for static files anyway?

Comment: @do-me I used a POST request on a different rout, not root.

Comment: Please be aware that the order in which endpoints (as well as independent applications, such as `StaticFiles`) are defined  **matters**. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804) for more details.

Answer (score 15):

The best and most simple solution that worked for me:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

api_app = FastAPI(title="api app")

@api_app.post("/set_influencers_to_follow")
async def set_influencers_to_follow(request):
    return {}

app = FastAPI(title="main app")

app.mount("/api", api_app)
app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="ui", html=True), name="ui")
```

If project structure is like:

```sh
├── main.py
├── ui
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── style.css
│   ├── script.js
```

Comment: It's better to separate your api routes from the route used for static files, I edited your answer for it.

Comment: I got a problem with `instance order`, I solved by placing `api_app = FastAPI(title="api app")` after `app = FastAPI(title="main app")`. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75045872/7009215

Answer (score 0):

The comments above assume that `index.html` is static ( like CSS or Javascript code ) and therefor, place the index.html inside a `static/` directory.

The following code can render either a simple static `index.html` even if *not* inside a static folder
OR you can render the `index.html` by using any Jinja2/Mako Templates option:

```
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

#
# Raw HTML option
# Or dumping the index.html into the response
#
@app.get("/", response=HTMLResponse)
async def home():
    return "<h1> HTML option </h1>"

#
# Mako templates
#
@app.get("/", response=HTMLResponse)
async def home():
    template = mylookup.get_template('templates/')
    return template.render_unicode('index.html')
```

The key point is the `response=HTMLResponse` in the decorator ... that makes FastAPI to return the header as `text/html` vs `application/json`