# How to serve React build with router via FastAPI

Tags: python, reactjs, backend, fastapi, create-react-app

To this point i was creating my React app seperated from the FastAPI backend. My react app was creating using create-react-app and then build with "npm run build". I got the build folder in my ReactApp folder. I uses Routes like so:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Users />} />
        <Route path="/doctors" element={<Doctors />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        <Route path="/schedules" element={<Schedules />} />
        <Route path="/visits" element={<Visits />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

I have no problem serving this app via "serve -s build" but my goal is to serve it on the same server as my backend. Therefore i coppied the inside of build folder to my FastApi project:

```
FastpAPI
  static/
    css/
    js/
    index.html
    manifest.json
    ...
  main.py
  auth.py
  models.py
  ...
```

Now in my main.py i have:

```
app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(auth.router)
app.include_router(api.router)


origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static", html=True), name="static")
```

When i run `uvicorn main:app --reload` and go to localhost:8000/, the page is blanc and console shows only CONTENT IS RUNNING. The same happens when i go to localhost:8000/index.html.

I really dont know where is the problem because i have already tried options provided in this questions:
[A minimal fastapi example loading index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916537/a-minimal-fastapi-example-loading-index-html)
[Deploy React's build folder via FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71823151/deploy-reacts-build-folder-via-fastapi)

both with serving index.html in "/" url and rerouting.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) helpful as well.

Comment: Unfortunatelly none of this answers helps me in anything, its simply not what im asking for. I've managed to render the index.html yet still not even one route defined in React app works, I just get 404 not found error.