# FastAPI serving static files through symlinks

Tags: python, fastapi, symlink, static-files, starlette

I have mounted the static directory in my FastAPI app using the following code:

```
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI(
    title="Title of the Application",
    description="Over all description of the application")
app.mount("/public", StaticFiles(directory='public'), name='public')
```

If I have a symlink pointing to a path outside the app folder, e.g.

```
/home/xyz/app/main.py
/home/xyz/app/index.html
/home/xyz/app/public/data -> /home/xyz/static/whatever.tgz
```

The FastAPI application can recognize the URL `xyz.com/public/index.html`, but it can't recognize `xyz.com/public/data`.

Is this doable? Unfortunately, I cannot use `FileResponse` due to the `blob` size being too large. I want to return the file with a simple link somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Starlette has recently added the [`follow_symlink` parameter in `StaticFiles`](https://www.starlette.io/staticfiles/#staticfiles) class, which is a boolean indicating if symbolic links for files and directories should be followed—by default, this value is set to `False`. One could set this to `True`, and hence, every symbolic link in the directory path should be followed. Example:

```py
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static", follow_symlink=True), name="static")
```

Given that there is a symlink called `data` in your `static` directory, you could then access, for instance, `http://localhost:8000/static/data/image.png` directly from your browser, or in your Jinja2 template, you could request files as follows:

```html
<img src="{{ url_for('static', path='data/image.png')}}" width="50%">
```

or, if there is an `images` sub-directory inside `data`:

```html
<img src="{{ url_for('static', path='data/images/image.png')}}" width="50%">
```

### Original Answer

It is doable, as long as you mount a [`StaticFiles`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/) instance on that specific path as well. For example:

```py
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
app.mount("/symlink", StaticFiles(directory="static/data"), name="publicsym")
```

Then, in your Jinja2 template you could request files as follows:

```html
<link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<img src="{{ url_for('symlink', path='/image.png')}}" width="50%">
```

or, if there is an `images` sub-directory inside `data`:

```html
<img src="{{ url_for('symlink', path='images/image.png')}}" width="50%">
```

Comment: What you posted works, thanks. Is it possible to somehow generate symlinks on the fly and then mount them? This option has a small security flaw that anyone with the link can access the files.

Comment: thats... annoying. Is there a way to force it to pick up those paths or defind the second one as ("public/data", StaticFiles(...))

Comment: ^ update, this does work. Just have to define nested/deeper paths BEFORE the root one. Mount those first.